# How to move down and move left the scroll bar that exists within the webpage?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to move the vertical and horizontal scrollbar that exists within the webpage itself, I couldn't do that with the below method,

When I inspected an element I got the below one,

```
<div id="DashboardPageContentDiv" class="DashboardPageContentDiv" style="height: 521px; overflow: auto;">
```

here is the method I created,

```
public void scrollbardown(RemoteWebDriver remoteWebDriver) throws Exception {
    try 
    {

        JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor)remoteWebDriver;
        jse.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,2500)", "");

    } 
   catch (Exception exc)
    {
            }

    }
```

This scrollbars exists with in the frame, here is the frame source code:

```
<iframe allowtransparency="true" id="symbUrlIFrame2" src="/cos/start.swe?SWECmd=GetCachedFrame&amp;SWEC=13&amp;SWEFrame=symbUrlIFrame2&amp;SRN=xaU5eD1S1IOkspAeHu524NMsHC5h5jzSUipwpmEq8bYb " height="800" width="100%" style="height: 607px; position: relative;"></iframe>
```

Comment: Is this inside any frame ?

Comment: @AnkurSingh, yes it is, I have added the source code for it in the description. Thank you for taking this up.

Comment: Please read why a [screenshot of HTML or code or error is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Consider updating the Question with formatted text based relevant HTML, code trials and error stack trace.

Comment: @DebanjanB, sure, modified.

Comment: switch to frame then try to run your code

Comment: Why are you trying to scroll the window? Just execute your actions and it should be scrolled for you in Java.

Comment: This works with the below code,  JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) remoteDriver; 
           WebElement a=remoteDriver.findElement(By.xpath(".//td[@id='titleView!1Subtitle' and contains(text(),'Time run: ')]"));
        js.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();",a );

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find the nearest element and use scrollintoview function to move there,  the below code works,

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) remoteDriver; 
WebElement 
a=remoteDriver.findElement(By.xpath(".//td[@id='titleView!1Subtitle' and 
contains(text(),'Time run: ')]"));
js.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();",a );
```